# Why when I change the CSS at the back end I dont get the result I am getting when I do it on chrome navigator?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

[image: wordpress backend]

[image: chrome frontend]

I am trying to put a width  of 100% on that load more button , I identified the css file with chrome navigator, i found the file at the back end of wordpress but when I change the width there nothing happen, why ?

Comment: Try to open the page in browser incognito mode, if this will work - your styles are cached and you need to force reload it

Comment: After you changed the CSS, did you clear the cache when testing it? Are you using some preprocessor, like SASS/LESS that you might forgotten to run? Do you have more CSS that might overwrite that one, like media queries? Please do some more debugging. It's pretty hard for us to know what's going on when we have no clue what you've tried or what your setup is. There're just too many unknowns.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys, the cache thing solved my problem

Any idea why when I try to add a smiley in the text of that button I get a bug ?

```
}
$button_class ='wcpr-load-more-reviews-button';
$button_class .= $is_shortcode ? ' shortcode-wcpr-load-more-reviews-button':'';
if (!empty($only_button)){
    echo sprintf('<div class="wcpr-load-more-reviews-button-container"><span class="%s" data-cpage="%s">%s</span></div>',
        esc_attr($button_class),esc_attr($cpage), esc_html__( 'Load 5 more ', 'woocommerce-photo-reviews' ));
    return;
}
```